# Issue with JSON in titanium

Tags: json, parsing, titanium

I have this createHTTPClient function:

```
xhr.onload = function () {

    var response = this.responseText;
    Ti.API.info("Response" + response);

    dataClean = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    Ti.API.info("Dataclean" + dataClean);
    //dataClean= response;
    app.myfunction();
```

The response show me the results ok but when I parse them the dataClean show me "[object Object]" 
Anyone knows the reason? Thanks in advance
PS. dataClean is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error. If you wish to print out an object you should use JSON.stringify(dataClean) to convert it to string in JSON notation